# How do I get python2.7 and 3.7 both installed in an alpine docker image

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I am trying to figure out a way that I can install both python2.7 and 3.7 in a lightweight alpine docker image.

Currently I am using the

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine3.9
```

Base image but would like to know how to get python2 installed as well.

Comment: Are you trying to run two different applications, one requiring a decade-old version of the language?  Running them in two separate containers is operationally easier and avoids this problem (among others).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use something like:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache python2
```

This will install the latest version of Python 2 as `python2` or `python2.7`. Python 3.7.3 will still be available using `python3`, or simply `python`.

Comment: Note that in the latest versions of alpine `python` or `python2` is no longer usable. For me what worked was pinning my alpine at `3.15`

Comment: This is not working node:18.13.0-alpine: unable to select packages:
[0m  python2 (no such package):
    required by: world[python2]